# Build Number of Android device is unique or not?

Tags: java, android, build-numbers

I attached the image to complete understanding of my question.

[Image of Build Number of my android device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V5kAf.png)

[image]

I have pointed out the build number of my android device.

Here is my 2 question.

1) Is it unique for every device or it can be same?

2) if it is unique how we can get it programmatically?

Comment: A build is a software version for a specific device - hence a build number is of course not unique. All devices with the same software version will have the same build id.

Comment: It is not unique, it can't be used to ID the device, there is a device id for that, it is not unique but it is randomly (or not ?) generated during the OS installation and can only be changed by reseting the device. You have a small chance to encounter two deviceID similar

Comment: Build Number is related the software version your device have, it's not related to the device itself, so it's not unique

Comment: See [Is there a unique Android device ID?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785485/is-there-a-unique-android-device-id) for an alternative

Comment: if you need unique id for device, I think Mac address will be useful

Comment: Thank you so much for clearing my concept

Comment: No @misha its not my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to uniquely identify a device you can use the `Secure` class in which is part of the Android's Settings package. which returns the Android ID as n unique 64-bit hex string. This way:

```
import android.provider.Settings.Secure;

private String android_id = Secure.getString(getContext().getContentResolver(),
                                                        Secure.ANDROID_ID);
```

However, this is non to be null sometimes. An all perfect complete solution to uniquely identify a device is yet to come up. There are various factors to be considered while acquiring the unique id of a device. Also see this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2853253/4738175)

Comment: Sir I agree with you.but i am confirming something that i have asked.

Comment: @ShafqatKamal The answer is no, the build number alone wont suffice, Why? The answer is provided in the final link in my Answer

Comment: Thank you soo much @OBX you saved my day

Comment: Mark the answer as complete if it was helpful :)